# Select customer with highest price of all his orders

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group

[image]i want to list customer id with highest sum of price of his orders. Please see graph oí orders down.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: Oracle database

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Hint: use select with sum and order by.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed7d0/9)**

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
         SELECT "customerid", SUM("price")
         FROM  Orders
         GROUP BY "customerid"
         ORDER BY SUM("price") DESC
      ) T
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: And if i want to select name of customer?

Comment: I dont see name of customer on your design :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by customer_id to get all prices of each customers.
Then sum these prices filter it with max( sum(price))or get first row by descending order of sum(price).

--for Oracle

```
select * from (Select c.name,c.id,sum(o.price) from Customer c
inner join order o on o.customer_id=c.id
group by c.name,c.id
order by sum(o.price)desc
)where rownum =1
```

--For sql server and mysql

```
Select top 1 c.name,c.id,sum(o.price) from Customer c
inner join order o on o.customer_id=c.id
group by c.name,c.id
order by sum(o.price)desc
```